# Limit as $n \to \infty$ of $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$ in the Fibonacci sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, fibonacci-numbers

Given that $x_n = \frac{\sqrt{5}+5}{10}  (\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2})^n + \frac{5 -    \sqrt{5}}{10}(\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2})^n$

How do you show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$ is the golden ratio?

Note: $(x_n)$ is the Fibonacci sequence

Comment: You simply compute $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_{n+1}  / x_n$. To simplify this note that when $n\to\infty$ the second term goes to zero so $x_n \simeq A\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n$.

Comment: ah yes! thanks, i didn't realise the modulus of 1-$\sqrt{5}$ < 2

Answer (score 3):

Using [Binet's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression) 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\phi^{n+1}-\psi^{n+1}\over\phi^{n}-\psi^{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\phi^{n+1}\over\phi^{n}}=\phi$$where $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$ and $\psi=\frac{1-\sqrt5}{2}$

---

Here's a non-rigorous but more elementary way:

Since $x_{n+1}=x_n+x_{n-1}$ for all $n>2$
$$
   \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} = 1 + {1\over{\frac{x_n}{x_{n-1}}}}$$
Let $n\to \infty$ and suppose the ratio between adjacent terms is convergent. Call the limit $L$
$$L=1+\frac1L\\
L^2-L-1=0$$
which is a quadratic in $L$. The positive root is $\phi$ by the quadratic formula, 
i.e. $$L=\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}=\phi$$in fact I think it's one of $\phi$'s definitions.